# Wifi randomly disconnects, drops out with an RTL 8187

Tags: 11.10, wireless, realtek

My connection randomly disconnects and prompts me again to input the passphrase for the wifi, I'm typing the password correctly and slowly. It does not connect until I turn off and turn on the Wireless. I'm using WPA personal and my wireless usb is RTL 8187

it seems like it is frequently dropping off the connection when I'm using Transmission bittorrent client, and seldomly if not.

here is the link of my thread on ubuntuforums, which unfortunately no one replied to it.

[ubuntuforums-zxca](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1890606)

Comment: I removed gnome network manager and tried Wicd. i'll update this if the problem is solved. Btw, how do I install the Wicd system tray icon on gnome?

Comment: ***update*** problem solved:D gnome network-manager is the problem why my connection frequently drops. Just install Wicd then removed gnome network-manager

Answer (score 2):

(*Posted by OP in the comments area*)

> problem solved:D gnome network-manager is the problem why my connection frequently drops. Just install Wicd then removed gnome network-manager